# index from mysql_fecth_row resul always 0

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, row

```
$desquery = "SELECT DISTINCT destination FROM stuff"; 
$des = mysql_query($desquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($datarow = mysql_fetch_row($des)){
for ($i=0;$i <count($datarow);$i++)
{
    if ($i==3) {echo "Hello";}
echo $datarow[$i];
echo "</br>";
echo $i;
echo "</br>";
}}
```

Give output 
Singapore
0
Haipong
0
sin
0
shanghai
0
hongkong
0
sidney
0
BANGKOK
0

My question why $i output not increase (always 0) so that the "hello" word never printed. Thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting only one column, so `count($datarow)` is every time exactly 1. The `while` loop loops over every row selected from database and the `for` cycle is trying to loop over selected columns, which is always 1 on every row, so `$i` is never increased and every time reinitialized to `0`.